# Android Contact list getting phone number

Tags: android, contacts, picker

hi i am trying this code in my app i can get the contact list but when i press on contact name i didnt get any thing in my edittext which i expected to get the contact phone number
sorry about my poor english

```
         public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view) {
        Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode=RESULT_OK) {
            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                Cursor cursor = null;
                String phone = "";
                try {
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
                    Iterator<String> iterate = keys.iterator();
                    while (iterate.hasNext()) {
                        String key = iterate.next();
                        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, key + "[" + extras.get(key) + "]");
                    }

                    Uri result = data.getData();
                    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got a contact result: "
                            + result.toString());

                    // get the contact id from the Uri
                    String id = result.getLastPathSegment();


                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },
                            null);

                    int PhoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);


                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                                                                        phone = cursor.getString(PhoneIdx);

                        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got number: " + phone);

                    } else {
                        Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "No results");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Failed to Number", e);
                } finally {
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                    EditText ponenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ednum);
                    ponenumber.setText(phone);

                    if (phone.length() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "No number found for contact.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

                break;
            }

        } else {
            Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "Warning: activity result not ok");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);

while (phones.moveToNext())
{
     String Name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)
     String Number=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

}
```

Comment: By far the fastest answer on here, however it should be noted that one would need to perform their own duplicate checking.

Answer (score 4):

You're actually really close- A few things.

- Your switch statement is basing off of the resultCode, not the request code.  Change that-  It should read "switch(requestCode)"
- Phone.DATA will work, but use Phone.NUMBER instead for readability sake:)
- Make sure you have the permission for android.permission.READ_CONTACTS set in your AndroidManifest.xml file, as an element inside the manifest element, but not in the application element.  The line should should look like this.

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

I made those modifications to your sample, and got working code.

Comment: Thx Alexander i change to "switch(requestCode)" and the phone.Data to Phone.Number and i am sure that i have the permission but it didnt work i can get the contact list but when i chosse contact nothing happened so please help me i dont know what to do and its really important to me

Comment: What showed up in your log output?  What device are you using to test?  What's the min/target SDK set to?

Answer (score 0):

you can change you code that you want get phone number,as the following

```
  List numberList = new ArrayList();
        Uri baseUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,contactId);
        Uri targetUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri,Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(targetUri,
                    new String[] {Phone.NUMBER},Data.MIMETYPE+"='"+Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE+"'",null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            numberList.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }
        cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an old post but it could help someone.

If you just have to Pick-up a contact, you can use the first code of the post without this part:

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
Iterator<String> iterate = keys.iterator();
while (iterate.hasNext()) {
    String key = iterate.next();
    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, key + "[" + extras.get(key) + "]");
}
```